# 2 android apps in one firebase project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I want to create client side app & Admin side app. When client sending a letter, Person who in admin app can approve or dismiss it. What is the best solution for this?

If I create 2 apps in one firebase project, It can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's no restrictions for having 2 android apps connected to your firebase frameworks.
Steps

1. You'll simply need to register both the apps to that particular firebase project with different package name.
2. Download both api files

> google-services.json

3. Put them in their respective app project files.

and that's it, both of the app will access the same firebase services.

Comment: Got it. After this steps, can i call streambuilder to other project database?

Comment: Two apps connected to one Firebase project means they both use the same Firebase database....and all the other firebase stuff eg. Firebase Auth